Debug a trigger within a PowerBuilder program?
I working on for maintaining a legacy project, my PowerBuilder version is 12.5 and my SQL Server is 2008 R2, I encountered a problem which when I tried to update the records within a datawindow in a PowerBuilder program, it triggered a trigger in a table in a SQL Server which update another table, meanwhile that table has a trigger as well , it went wrong in the second table. that's why I print some variables in the trigger of second table, I'd like to show you the trigger of first table
ALTER Trigger  [table1_Insert] 
On  [table1] For Insert
As
.........
.........
declare @ln_lestnum numeric(12,4)
declare @ln_num  numeric(9,3)
if exists (select att_no from inserted where source='in' and att_no <> '' and LOWER(LEFT( att_no, 3)) ='bac' )
begin
   update s 
      set s.process_num = s.process_num + i.process_num,
      s.is_process = case when s.back_num  - i.process_num > 0.000001 then 'yes' else 'ok' end
      from inserted i,secondtable s  
      where ltrim(rtrim(i.att_no)) =  ltrim(rtrim(s.back_no)) and  
      i.prod_no = s.prod_no and 
      i.prod_add = s.prod_add and 
      i.batch_no = s.batch_no 
      if @@rowcount = 0 
       begin
          print('errors encountered update returning goods numbers')
          eturn
       end
  end 

here is my update trigger for second table , this isn't working, the problem is prodno and batchno and prodadd is totally all empty or space, it's so strange.
ALTER trigger [secondtable_update]
on  [secondtable]
for update
as

declare @ln_lestnum numeric(9,3)
declare @ln_newbacknum  numeric(9,3)
declare @ln_oldbacknum  numeric(9,3)
declare @ls_prodno char(8),@ls_batchno char(12),@ls_prodadd char(12)

select  @ls_prodno = i.prod_no,@ls_batchno=i.batch_no,@ls_prodadd=prod_add,
        @ln_newbacknum  = i.back_num from inserted i
select  @ln_oldbacknum = d.back_num from deleted  d

print('prodno '+@ls_prodno+' batchno'+@ls_batchno+' prod_add'+ @ls_prodadd) -- I tried to print the values of the variables I need to know but they're all empty, this is strange
return
..........

any suggestions or ideas I'll be appreciated, thank you so much. there's no way for debug a trigger on PowerBuilder
I'm looking forward to seeing in the second trigger, it print the real @prodno @batchno @prodadd as the same value in the first trigger, thank you so much

Your second trigger, incorrectly assumes only a single row in Inserted & Deleted, whereas in fact they can contain 0->N. You have to write your trigger accordingly to handle a set, potentially an empty set. The way all SQL needs to be written as its no procedural. You need to check the official resources available and teach yourself how SQL Server triggers work.

Also debug your trigger in SSMS.

@DaleK I appreciate your helps, it sounds like I need to using cursors for reading each row of records it inserted or deleted, thank you so much

No! You totally shouldn't be using a cursor... you should be using set-based operations. Or else not doing it in a trigger. Instead of asking us what is wrong with your trigger you should be showing us the results you want to achieve and asking for help achieving that. As it stands we have no idea what the intention of the second trigger is so cannot help.

Anytime you think cursors in SQL you need to stop and take stock... because they should only be required in rare, often badly designed, scenarios. SQL is based on sets, you need to get into a set-based mindset.

You desperately need to get your upgrade path sorted out. SQL Server 2008 r2 has been fully unsupported for several years now.

@SeanLange all right
